# How to create all combinations of one column's items and choose one of the other columns each time?

Tags: python, pandas

For instance, let's consider the following DataFrame:

```
    id  metric_a  metric_b
0   a     1         2
1   b     10        20
2   c     30        40
```

The resulting dataframe would consist of all the combinations of `id`, that is n<sup>2</sup> rows (square matrix).

In our case, since we have 3 unique ids, we would get 9 rows in total.

Now, given that each row is actually a pair `x-y` of ids, I'd like to have `metric_a` for `x` and `metric_b` for `y`, where `x` and `y` are simply the two ids of the given row.

To illustrate this:

```
    x   y  metric_a  metric_b
0   a   a    1         2
1   a   b    1         20
2   a   c    1         40
3   b   a    10        2
4   b   b    10        20
5   b   c    10        40
6   c   a    30        2
7   c   b    30        20
8   c   c    30        40
```

One way to achieve this is by first creating all possible combinations with `itertools.product` and then merging the initial dataframe two times.
First time, to bring the metric for `x` and the second time to bring the metric for `y`.

Another way that came to my mind is:

```py
# creating all the combinations of ids
pd.DataFrame(list(itertools.product(df['id'], df['id'])))

# creating all the combinations of metrics
pd.DataFrame(list(itertools.product(df['metric_a'], df['metric_b'])))

# some more code to concat those two horizontally..
```

However, I think that there should be a more elegant solution that I can't think of at the moment.

Also, could ideas around using `MultiIndex.from_product` and then reindexing work?

Any help is more than welcome!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use a cross [`merge`](https://pandas.pydata.org/docs/reference/api/pandas.merge.html):

```
(df.drop(columns='metric_b')
   .merge(df.drop(columns='metric_a'), how='cross')
   .rename(columns=lambda x: x.replace('id_', ''))
)
```

Output:

```
   x  metric_a  y  metric_b
0  a         1  a         2
1  a         1  b        20
2  a         1  c        40
3  b        10  a         2
4  b        10  b        20
5  b        10  c        40
6  c        30  a         2
7  c        30  b        20
8  c        30  c        40
```